# 4.0 GUI rendering in 2.3.3

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a project in android 2.3.3 and want to add attractive GUI . Simple drag drop does not seem to be very good enough .

How do I go about to do it . any ICS compatibly libraries for GUI ?

The library pages from google search where of ActionBar . I want ICS like display of my whole application

***In short I want ICS like look in 2.3.3 device ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this library Bringing Holo Theme from Android 4.1 to 2.1 and above.
[HoloEveryWhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere)

Comment: downloaded library . what next  .. how to import library :o